# Flask - Access request object from method in class

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, flask

I'm trying to access the request.form field from inside a method in a class that I use to create the Flask app, but I got everytime and empty request

```
from flask import Flask, request
class MyAPIClass(object):

    def __init__(self, address="0.0.0.0", port=5000):
        self.address = address
        self.port = port
        self.app = Flask(__name__)
        self.logger = self.app.logger
        self.app.add_url_rule('/create/<id>', 'create', self.create, methods=['POST'])

    def create(self, od):
       root = request.form.get('root')
       home = request.form.get('home')
       size = int(request.form.get('size', 0))
       print('CREATE {} -> {} -> {} -> {}'.format(id, root, home, size))

    def start(self):
       self.app.run(debug=True, host=self.address, port=self.port)
```

I have tried to use Flask.request_started to save the request object inside a field in my class but seems to not working.

This is how I create and start the class

```
from MyLib import MyAPIClass
api = MyAPIClass()
api.start()
```

And then using postman I send a POST to the url

```
curl --request POST \
  --url http://127.0.0.1:5000/create/123 \
  --header 'home: r/h' \
  --header 'root: r' \
  --header 'size: 100'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you include usage example? how are you calling the class and how are you passing the form to it?

Comment: What about passing the form data as a method parameter?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Added the example, I don't want to add the parameters in the uri because some of that are URI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a HTTP Header is different than a form data (which is actually POST data formatted as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`).

Using the curl command you posted, you add HTTP headers instead of form data. Use it like that:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url http://127.0.0.1:5000/create/123 \
  --form 'home: r/h' \
  --form 'root: r' \
  --form 'size: 100'
```

Comment: Shame on me, I have used postman putting parameters in the wrong place.

Thank you so much!